# How to implement on Mac OS X to "refresh" all viewing apps if a file is changed?

Tags: macos, cocoa

It is quite amazing that on TextMate, I can change a line in a local html file (the web sharing on Mountain Lion, using url such as `http://macmini.local/~mike/page.html`), and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> right inside TextMate, and the webpage on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all will refresh the content automatically.  I wonder how it can be done, and does it depend on whether the app is observing that file (or it can choose to not observe).  I heard that iOS has KVO that can function similarly to bindings on Mac OS X, but don't know if the above behavior is done by OS X bindings?).

Answer (score 2):

KVO and Bindings work on objects, not files.

There are a few ways to notify other apps that a file has changed:

- [`FNNotify`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FNNotify) is a deprecated function from the old File Manager. It takes an `FSRef`. There's also `FNNotifyByPath`; you can guess what that takes.
- [`-[NSWorkspace noteFileSystemChanged:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/noteFileSystemChanged%3a) takes a path and likewise notifies anything that may be watching the file.
- [File Coordination](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileCoordinators/FileCoordinators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH11-SW1) is a separate system. It *may* integrate with the above, more primitive methods, but I'm not sure and wouldn't count on it. File coordinators handle the notifying; file presenters (which include documents in document-based apps) handle the watching.

*Some* apps will notice changes without you doing any of the above because they have older, hand-written code to watch files using `kevent`, `dispatch_source`, FSEvents, or some other means, but most apps don't undertake such extra measures.

If your app is document-based, you don't need to do anything. The document machinery handles everything for you. You just implement the reading and writing methods as normal.

For a non-document-based app, I would implement File Coordination first, and only use `noteFileSystemChanged:` after witnessing that FC isn't notifying an app that I care about.

Comment: -[NSWorkspace noteFileSystemChanged:] Is deprecated. You should use FSEvents right now